# How to define in ZFC transfinite hierarchies of proper classes (with an example usefull for proof theory)

Tags: logic, set-theory, proof-theory, transfinite-recursion

I was studying some Proof Theory in Pohlers' *Proof Theory: first step into impredicativity* , and I found myself facing a Set Theory's problem.

We need to define this transfinite hierarchy of *proper classes*:

$$\mathcal{C} (0) = H  $$

$$\mathcal{C} ( \alpha + 1) = \mathcal{C} (\alpha) ' $$

$$ \mathcal{C} (\lambda) = \bigcap \{ \mathcal{C} (\delta) | \delta < \lambda \}  ,\ if\ \lambda\ is\ a\ limit $$

Here, *H* is the (proper) class of principal ordinals (or additively indecomposable) and, if *M* is a class, *M'* is its derivative class (the precise definition of these concepts are not important for our pourposes). Those familiar with proof theory will see that this is just a step toward the definition of the hierarchy of Veblen functions, wich, in turn, is used to build a notation system for ordinals below $ \Gamma_0 $.

Well, the problem is this: is it possible to justify in ZFC a definition like that? If it is, How can I do that? The usual form of general transfinite recursion theorem (wich is yet a theorem-scheme) can justify the definition of hierarchies like the hierarchy of Aleph Numbers, or the hierarchy of Constructible Sets, and so on, *where at each step of the recursion what is produce is a **set*** , not a proper class.
Just for clarity, the "usual form of general transfinite recursion theorem" that I'm talking about is this (see, for example, *Set theory: an introduction to independence proofs*, Kunen, 1980, pag. 25) :

Let $\psi(x,y)$ be a formula such that ZFC proves $\forall x \exists! y\  \psi(x,y)$ ; let's call G(x) the unique y such that $\psi(x,y)$ (i.e. , G is a class-function).
Then, we can write another formula $\phi(u,w)$ such that:

1- ZFC proves $\forall \alpha \exists!w \phi(\alpha,w)$; let's call F($\alpha$) the unique w such that $\phi(\alpha,w)$. Here, obviously, $\alpha$ ranges over the class of ordinals.

2- ZFC proves $\forall \alpha\ [ F(\alpha)=G(F\lceil \alpha)]$

Now, the problem is that the "condition of existence" I need is not satisfied, as outputs of $\mathcal C$ are proper classes; so, this definition's pattern is not available for the definition of the hierarchy above mentioned.
Any suggestion about how to handle this kind of situation in ZFC?

Thank you.

Comment: You said "$M'$ is its derivative class (the precise definition of these concepts are not important for our porpoises)". But actually, the precise definition of $M'$ in terms of $M$ *is* important here, as it affects whether or not we can indeed define this kind of thing transfinitely. So you should say exactly what $M'$ is. (E.g. if the derivative operator $C\mapsto C'$ gives the class of all ordinals $\alpha$ such that $(V_\alpha,C\cap V_\alpha)\preceq_1(V,C)$, then you won't in general be able to define $C(\omega)$, because if it's unbounded in the ordinals, it would give a truth predicate.)

Comment: Also, therefore, your concern about whether such a definition can be made in ZFC is well-justified.

Comment: Dear @FarmerS, thank you for your answer. Here, given a class M of ordinals, with its derivative M' we mean the class { a in M | En_M (a) = a }, where En_M is the "enumerating function of M", wich is the unique function from the class of ordinals to M that "counts" the elements of M preserving the order.
In our case, for each a, C(a) is a proper class (so also En_C(a), wich is used to define C(a+1), is a class-function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define the kind of recursion you specified directly for set initial segments of $H$, i.e. starting with $H\cap\alpha$ for any given $\alpha$, instead of the whole $H$. This proceeds with the usual transfinite recursion that you mention. We use this to define the recursion instead, and show that it works.

For any ordinal $\alpha$ and $C_\alpha=H\cap\alpha$, define sets $C_\alpha(\beta)$ as follows:

- $C_\alpha(0)=C_\alpha$,
- $C_\alpha(\beta+1)=C_\alpha(\beta)'$,
- $C_\alpha(\beta)=\bigcap_{\gamma<\beta}C_\alpha(\gamma)$
  for limits $\beta$.

Observe that $C_{\alpha}(\beta)\subseteq\alpha$ for all $\beta$,
and if $\alpha_0<\alpha_1$
then $C_{\alpha_0}(\beta)=C_{\alpha_1}(\beta)\cap\alpha_0$ for all $\beta$.

For all ordinals $\beta$, define $C(\beta)=\{\xi\bigm|\exists\alpha\ [\xi\in C_\alpha(\beta)]\}$.

So $\xi\in C(\beta)$ iff $\xi\in C_\alpha(\beta)$ for some $\alpha>\xi$
iff $\xi\in C_\alpha(\beta)$ for all $\alpha>\xi$.

This gives a uniform definition of classes $C(\beta)$, done in ZF.
Now observe that they satisfy the recursion that you specified, i.e.
$C(0)=H$, $C(\beta+1)=C(\beta)'$, and intersections at limits.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to me that actually this works. So, beside the solution of the particular example, here another usefull thing that we could observe: in case like that, where we want to define a hierarchy of proper classes by transfinite recursion, we cannot say in principle if we can or not justify the definition in ZFC (i.e., there is not a general pattern as for sets); rather, we have to watch for the particular case and find out if we can "paraphrase" it in a way that we can justify in ZFC (so, now, I can understand better why I was wrong not specifying the meaning of M').

Comment: Indeed @Matteo__, that's a good message to take away from all this! For an extremal example, think about how much easier this question would have been if we replaced $'$ in the second clause with some trivial operation, say $\mathcal{C}(\alpha + 1) = \mathcal{C}(\alpha)$.

Comment: Dear @Farmer S , could you add some details about how to prove "if α_0<α_1 then C_α_0(β)=C_α_1(β)∩α_0 for all β " ? Also, I would like to understand better how can I prove that " Now observe that they satisfy the recursion that you specified, i.e. C(0)=H, C(β+1)=C(β)′, and intersections at limits."
Intuitively, I can see the point; but, trying to be more formal, I'm not sure about how to prove it. Thank you.

Comment: Just a hint: prove both of these statements by (transfinite) induction on $\beta$. (Do the statement about $C_{\alpha_0}(\beta)$ and $C_{\alpha_1}(\beta)$ first. There is no induction on $\alpha_0,\alpha_1$ needed; just let $\alpha_0<\alpha_1$ be any two ordinals, and use induction on $\beta$.)